# Internal Notion URL for Image Blocks (Type= File) not working

Tags: notion-api

I have created a Python script to split Notion pages based on specific logic.
This works great for all block types except Image.  I get the following error: `{"object": "error", "status": 400, "code": "validation_error", "message": "body failed validation: body.children[0].image.external should be defined, instead was -undefined-."}`.
The problem is probably that I am passing an internal Notion url from an image on the original page.
JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "children": [
        {
            "object": "block",
            "type": "image",
            "image": {
                "caption": [],
                "type": "file",
                "file": {
                    "url": "https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/secure.notion-static.com/79139e41-ff5e-46c9-9148-23b4d2be16d5/00006.jpeg?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAT73L2G45EIPT3X45%2F20211121%2Fus-west-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20211121T203556Z&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-Signature=c797152dde12edbc2b4991d6bfe017166a86aead6c49d96912ea2711cbdd3c2e&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&x-id=GetObject",
                    "expiry_time": "2021-11-21T21:35:56.923Z"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this option not supported yet?
I assumed based on the documentation that one can pass an existing Notion url reference to the Append block children endpoint.
Many thanks in advance for your reply.
It would be so great if this would work!
Jaco

Answer (score 2):

My question is already answered by Alfonso from Notion:

Hi Jaco, Thanks for writing in. The issue here appears to be the file URL that you are using. Unfortunately, you cannot use the URL returned from the Notion API for this. When a URL for a file hosted on Notion is returned in the response, we send a AWS URL that is valid for 1 hour. However this URL cannot be used to create a block. File must be externally hosted in order to create file blocks in Notion.
More details are available in our file object documentation.

I hope this helps. Cheers! –